# Sequence from two others

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

There are two increasing sequences $a$ and $b$.
The first is of $n$ legth, the other one of $m$ length.
They are all distinct, i.e. the set of all elements from $a$ and $b$ consists of $n+m$ elements.

How many increasing sequencies are there so that we take, in turns:
the $(2k+1)$-th element of the desired sequence from $a$, the $2k$-th element from $b$
or
the $(2k+1)$-th element of the desired sequence from $b$, the $2k$-th element from $a$?

Comment: Thanks, @Filburt for the edit.
My LaTeX is a bit rusty.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. Do you just mean that the new sequences must alternate taking elements from $a$ and from $b$, while never decreasing? Are there any requirements on the length of the new sequence, or could the new sequence consist of, for example, just $a_7$?

Comment: As regards the first question: yes. The answer to the 2nd of your questions is that it can be of any length (with the exception of $0$).

Comment: This seems to depend heavily on what the sequences $a$ and $b$ are. If both sequences are constant (and trivially non-decreasing) then there are exponentially many solutions; if every element of $a$ is larger than any element of $b$, then there are only $m+n+mn$, because we're done as soon as we take an element of $a$.

Comment: Thanks. I see that all elements from $a$ and $b$ have to be distinct. So that a set containing all $a$ and $b$ elements has $n+m$ elements.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one increasing sequence consisting of all the elements of $a$ and all the elements of $b$ together.  It may or may not meet your condition on having the elements come alternately from $a$ and $b$, so there is either $0$ or $1$.  In particular, unless $m=n$ or $m=n\pm 1$ it cannot and there will be none.

Comment: I did not mean all the elements of $a$ and all the elements of $b$. I just meant any of their elements. If there is something wrong with problem statement, please let me know.

Comment: I don't think we can say anything useful about the general case.  For example, you could have all the elements of $b$ greater than all the elements of $a$.  Your new sequence could only be $2$ long in that case and there would be $mn$ of them.  On the other hand the elements of $a$ could alternate with the elements of $b$ and we could be able to form quite long sequences.

Comment: Yeah, I see it sheds some light on the problem. It is not something I found in a book, but this: https://codility.com/programmers/challenges/chromium2017/ in my own words. Will look rather for dynamic programming and/or recursive solution.

Comment: @RossMillikan - they can also be 1 long in that case, so the total is $mn + m +n$, as Misha Lavrov says.

Comment: For a dynamic programming solution, I would note that you can have the empty sequence, a sequence that starts with the smallest element of a, a sequence that starts with the smallest element of b, or a sequence that includes neither smallest element.  Now call a similar routine with the remaining elements of $a,b$.  After you start, you have to keep track of which set the next element has to come from.